# How can I make torch tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I want to make a torch tensor composed of only 1 or -1.

I just try to use `torch.empty()` and `torch.randn()`.

```
tmp = torch.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(4, 4))
tmp[tmp==0] = -1
tmp
>> tensor([[ 1, -1, -1,  1],
           [-1,  1,  1, -1],
           [-1, -1,  1,  1],
           [-1,  1, -1,  1]])
```

However, I don`t know what method is most efficient in time.

And I want to make this code to one line as possible because this code is positioned at `__init__ ()`

Comment: You can do `(torch.empty(4, 4).uniform_(-1, 1) * 1e8).clamp(min=-1, max=1)` but the  `.uniform_(-1, 1) ` function can produce some zero values with very low probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```py
tmp = -1 + 2 * torch.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(4, 4))
```